# Accessing elements of the message body inside a Camel EIP bean

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have a Camel route in which I'm using the Content Enricher EIP. So my route looks like this:

```
AggregationStrategy aggregationStrategy = new TestAggregationStrategy(); 

from("timer:myTimer?repeatCount=1")
.setBody(simple("{\"channel\": \"orderbook\", \"market\": \"BTC/USD\", \"type\": \"update\", \"data\": {\"time\": 1626139758.986094, \"checksum\": 195176195, \"bids\": [[32965.0, 0.0], [32962.0, 3.4015]], \"asks\": [], \"action\": \"update\"}}"))
.setHeader(MongoDbConstants.CRITERIA, constant(Filters.eq("market", "BTC/USD")))
.enrich("mongodb:mongo?database=dev&collection=order&operation=findOneByQuery", aggregationStrategy)
.log("Test: ${body}");
```

And inside TestAggregationStrategy I have two exchanges, the original and the resource.

```
public class TestAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange original, Exchange resource) {
        System.out.println("Original: " + original.getMessage().getBody().toString());
        
    
        String bidsJsonQuery = "$.data.bids";
        DocumentContext updateContext = JsonPath.parse(original.getMessage().getBody().toString());
        List<String> updateJsonString = updateContext.read(bidsJsonQuery);
        
        System.out.println(resource.getMessage().getBody());
        
        //ArrayList test = (ArrayList) resource.getMessage().getBody(List.class);
        Object test = resource.getMessage().getBody();
        System.out.println("Test: " + test);

        
        System.out.println("Resource: " + resource.getMessage().getBody()); 
        return resource; 
    }
}
```

I can get to the message content with resource.getMessage().getBody(), which returns an object of some kind. If I throw this into a println(), it prints the Mongo document. When I examine the resource exchange with the debugger, it looks like this:

exchange > in > body ("Document")

Which contains an array of hash maps. In this example, one of the hash maps has a key of "bids" with a value of an array list.

Are you able to access these values directly? The array list? I've been experimenting and I can't get past the getBody().

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code (Jsonpath query and conversion) is OK, but "bids" is not a `List<String>`

In the message body you set "bids" is a `List<List<Double>>`.

When I take your Json String I can extract the "bids" in pure Java like this

```
    String jsonString = "{\"channel\": \"orderbook\", \"market\": \"BTC/USD\", \"type\": \"update\", \"data\": {\"time\": 1626139758.986094, \"checksum\": 195176195, \"bids\": [[32965.0, 0.0], [32962.0, 3.4015]], \"asks\": [], \"action\": \"update\"}}";
    String bidsJsonQuery = "$.data.bids";
    DocumentContext updateContext = JsonPath.parse(jsonString);
    List<List<Double>> bids = updateContext.read(bidsJsonQuery);
    for (List<Double> bid : bids) {
        for (Double singleBid : bid) {
            logger.info("{}", singleBid);
        }
    }
```

The output of the logger is

```
32965.0
0.0    
32962.0
3.4015
```

By the way: in your code you parse the `original` message body. In the text you write about the `resource` body. Is this a mistake in your code?

Comment: The `original` message body is a string. So I need to parse that. It comes from a websocket. The `resource` comes from MongoDB, so it looks like Camel is able to parse it. I added some more detail to my OP. I can get the message body -- I put that in `test`. But I can't figure out how to access all the LinkedHashMaps.